# C - where is constant located in a process's memory?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

From the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993435/why-are-constants-stored-in-the-text-segment-in-a-c-memory-map) I see that the *constant* variable must be in the program's process memory **Text segment**, and if I'm understanding everything correct - it's really is:

```
int main() {

    static const char somedata[8192] = "somedata";

    while (1) {
        printf("\tAddress of main: %p\n", main);
        printf("\tMy process ID : %d\n", getpid());
        printf("\tArray Some first address: %p\n", &somedata[1]);
        sleep(10);
    };

    return 0;
}
```

This gives me result:

> ```
> Address of main: 0x4bc38b971a
> My process ID : 633
> Array Some first address: 0x4bc38b9881
> ```

After running it - `/proc/maps` confirms it:

> ```
> $ cat /proc/633/maps 
> 4bc38b9000-4bc38bc000 r-xp 00000000 fe:01 19664256
> ```

`0x4bc38b9881` is *325403252865* in dec, `0x4bc38b9000 - 0x4bc38bc000` is  *325403250688-325403262976*, and *325403252865* is between those borders, all looks correct.

The `size` also tells it is in the `text`:

> ```
> $ size mem_lay_inc_text_print
>    text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
>   10097     608       8   10713    29d9 mem_lay_inc_text_print
> ```

But [this](http://www.developerinsider.in/memory-layout-representation-of-c-program/) (and a lot of similar) topic says - **constant** is in the **Initialized Data Segment** instead on **Code segment**:

> Initialized data stores all global, static, **constant**,

So - where the truth is? Or I'm just misunderstanding something?

Maybe *4bc38b9000-4bc38bc000* contains both **Init. data** and **Text** segments?

No, it doesn't:

```
...
static int i = 100;

while (1) {
    printf("Address of main: %p\n", main);
    printf("My process ID : %d\n", getpid());
    printf("Array Some first address: %p\n", &somedata[1]);
    printf("Int I address: %p\n", &i);
...
```

Now from `size`'s results I see that `data` became bigger (`data 612` instead of `608` from the first result), `maps` also says same:

> ```
> ...
> Int I address: 0xea335af040
> ...
> ```

And `maps`:

> ```
> $ cat /proc/8859/maps
> ea333ac000-ea333af000 r-xp 00000000 fe:01 19664256
> ea335ae000-ea335af000 r--p 00002000 fe:01 19664256
> ea335af000-ea335b0000 rw-p 00003000 fe:01 19664256
> ```

*0xea335af040* is in the *ea335af000-ea335b0000* with `rw-p`, which is `data`...

Really confused here...

> ```
> $ gcc --version
> gcc (GCC) 7.1.1 20170630
> ```

So the question is: where the constant is stored - in Initialized data, or Text segment? Or it depends on compiler/OS?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Constants will be on location where linker puts them.

Comment: @tilz0R Where constant stored - in Initialized data, or Text segment?

Comment: Basically it depends on the compiler.  I don't pay much attention to this stuff any more -- it's the compiler's job, why worry about it? -- but I believe it's pretty common these days to put `const` strings (which might also include string literals) in the text segment, and writable strings in the initialized data segment.

Comment: @SteveSummit > why worry about it // Just trying to understand how it works.

Comment: @setevoy I understand, which is why I answered at all, I was basically just offering my excuse for why I'm not sure about the answer.  And while this stuff is interesting, one has to be careful about "learning" it as if it's gospel, because of course it varies widely, especially between systems, but also even under one system as it evolves over time.

Comment: objdump should give you definitive answer. Remove includes first. Otherwise I would use gdb and e.g. info address somedata?

Comment: You are conflating two different things. Constant data is in the *section* `.rodata` (read-only data) which is distinct from `.text` section. Both `.text` and `.rodata` sections are packed into the same *segment*. https://lwn.net/Articles/531148/

Comment: Thanks, @n.m.! Now seems I got it... So, `.text` and `.rodata` sections will be placed in the Code segment of a running program's memory, all correct here. 
Just still wondering why developerinsider.in (and similar) says "Initialized data segment stores all global, static, constant [...]" instead of Code segment?

Comment: @setevoy: Because developerinsider.in (and others) were either misinformed, plain wrong, or just ignored some of the details? To err is human.

Comment: Tnahks, @NominalAnimal. Now I can sleep in peace :-)

Comment: @setevoy: Most good authors would like to be informed about any errors they've made, so they can correct them in the next edition. If that site has an email contact person/address, perhaps you could send them a nice, polite, but firm email telling the author about the issue? Include the page URL, of course. (I'd also include my proof, i.e. your program above, so the author can easily verify the bug.) Same approach works for software projects, by the way. :)

Comment: @NominalAnimal Good point! Will do and maybe will get reply with some explanations as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to write an extended comment here rather than the comments because of space and formatting limitations.

To begin with, the memory layout link in at https://developerinsider.co/memory-layout-representation-of-c-program/ is not wrong; it just fails to mention that it is attempting a fully generalized discussion over ALL OSes. The four layout concepts to come away with that are universal are: 1) Code, 2) Data allocated at build time (this gets messy), and the two flavors of dynamic data: 3) Stack and 4) Heap. As shown. It neglects to mention the many actual mechanics needed for a dynamically linked environment, such as the Global Offset Table (.got).

One important distinction that I believe is fuzzy for the OP is executable file layout versus the running process memory layout. Executable file layout, such as ELF, is the latent bits on disk that contain the blueprint for a process. This is where it makes sense to talk of all the specific *sections* and where the `objdump` tool applies. `objdump -h foo` will in fact show 30 sections.

The executable loader in the Linux kernel maps these many sections to just a few *memory regions* to minimize the complexity and overhead of managing memory.

The next important distinction is between generalized Unix behavior versus the specifics of Linux where, at least in conception, performance on cheap hardware is at a premium over elegance and adherence to clean separations. Hence in the referenced link:

> For that reason, the .rodata section, which contains read-only
>   initialized data, is packed into the same segment that contains the
>   .text section.

This is unfortunate, because read-only initialized data *has totally unnecessary execute permissions attached*. Almost certainly a hardened variation of Linux would not do this at the expense of slight memory or CPU wastage.

Here's my code (I note you're using 1-based arrays -- oops, that's not how C works!) -- which tries to show read-only versus read-write mappings:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */
#include <sys/types.h> /* getpid */
#include <unistd.h> /* getpid */
#include <sys/select.h>

const char small_ro_global[  16] = "small ro global";
char       small_rw_global[  16] = "small ro global";
const char   big_ro_global[8192] = "  big ro global";
char         big_rw_global[8192] = "  big rw global";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  /* small_ro_global[1] = 'b'; compile error */
  small_rw_global[1] = 'c'; /* ensure writable */

  printf("Address of main: %p\n", main);
  printf("My process ID : %d\n", getpid());

  printf("small_ro_global: %p big_ro_global: %p small_rw_global: %p big_rw_global: %p\n",
         small_ro_global, big_ro_global, small_rw_global, big_rw_global);

  /* waits forever */
  select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

GCC: v. 4.8.4  GNU/Linux distribution: Ubuntu 15.10 Hardware: Intel 64-bit
Output:

```
Address of main: 0x4005cd
My process ID : 5788
small_ro_global: 0x400700 big_ro_global: 0x400720 small_rw_global: 0x603060 big_rw_global: 0x603080
```

`/proc/5788/maps` excerpt. Note what lands in 1st vs. 3rd section but nothing lands in 2nd section:

```
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1947                               /root/foo
00602000-00603000 r--p 00002000 ca:01 1947                               /root/foo
00603000-00606000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 1947                               /root/foo
```

Finally thanks to that link just learned about `readelf -l` which gives the below. In particular see segment 02 containing .text and .rodata sections.

```
 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   03     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     .eh_frame_hdr 
   07     
   08     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got
```

From the documentation on `proc` (5) we learn that the 2nd *in memory segment* (permission: read-only, not executable), and correlating that with `objdump`, is for process mechanics: dynamic linking and exception handling. It contains the sections: `.eh_frame_hdr`, `.eh_frame`, `.init_array`, `.fini_array`, `.jcr`, `.dynamic`, and `.got`.

So, nothing you can point in your code will ever show in that region.